# How to hide WooCommerce product total sales in Shop and Category Pages

Tags: woocommerce

How to hide the product total sales number in the Shop Page and in the every Category Page?

Does somebody could explain me if there any option that I have select/diselect or if you share me PHP o CSS code to solve the problem.

Comment: This feature doesn't exist by default in WooCommerce, so your theme or a 3rd party plugin is doing that.